# Error when attempting to parse JSON data from string

Tags: node.js, json

I am trying to get my code ready to send json back to my chatbot, can someone please tell me why i am getting an error on this:

```
    const data = '{ "Company Name": companyname, "service type": service }'
        try {
          const user = JSON.parse(data)
        } catch(err) {
          console.error(err)
}
```

this is my full lower code all working apart from this

```
//=======================================================================================
//  Get the Client data from database
//=======================================================================================
app.get("/Getcompany", function(request, response) {
  const cname = request.query.cname, query = `select * from clientdata_nsw where companyname  = ${connection.escape(
    cname
  )}`;
  connection.query(query, function(err, rows) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return;
    }
    const data = '{ "Company Name": companyname, "service type": service }'
        try {
          const user = JSON.parse(data)
        } catch(err) {
          console.error(err)
}
    rows.forEach(function(result) {
      console.log(
        result.companyname,
        result.service,
        result.phone,
        result.open_times,
        result.rating_facebook,
        result.rating_goggle
      );
    });
    response.json({})
  });

})



  // listen for requests :)
var listener = app.listen(process.env.PORT, function () {
  console.log('Your app is listening on port ' + listener.address().port);
});
```

Comment: What is the error you are currently getting?

Comment: C:\Users\Adam.Wolarczuk\Desktop\Projects\nodetest>node db.js
Your app is listening on port 60402
(node:22868) [DEP0096] DeprecationWarning: timers.unenroll() is deprecated. Please use clearTimeout instead.
C:\Users\Adam.Wolarczuk\Desktop\Projects\nodetest\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:78
        throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
        ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token c in JSON at position 18
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Query._callback 
C:\Users\Adam.Wolarczuk\Desktop\Projects\nodetest>

Comment: @AdamWolarczuk Can you console the value of cname? are you getting an actual value?

Comment: i sure am i am getting the company name is am passing

Answer (score 1):

Error is present in the first line itself

```
const data = '{ "Company Name": companyname, "service type": service }'
JSON.parse(data)
```

You have to escape companyname and service because those cannot be parsed by JSON parser else use a JS object rather than parsing a string and forming a JS object. I am not understanding why you have those lines in the code because they are not used for anything at all.

```
const data = '{ "Company Name": "companyname", "service type": "service" }'
JSON.parse(data)
```

The entire code rewritten using ES6 standards.

```
const PORT = process.env.PORT;

app.get("/Getcompany", async (request, response) => {
  const cname = request.query.cname,
    query = `select * from clientdata_nsw where companyname  = ${connection.escape(
      cname
    )}`;
  const data = '{ "Company Name": "companyname", "service type": "service" }';
  try {
    const user = JSON.parse(data);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
  try {
    const results = await connection.query(query);
    results.forEach(row => {
      console.log(
        row.companyname,
        row.service,
        row.phone,
        row.open_times,
        row.rating_facebook,
        row.rating_goggle
      );
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
  response.json({});
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Your app is listening on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

Comment: I am using it in this part

    );
    });
    response.json({})
  });

})

knowing me i am doing it completely wrong :)

Comment: i added it  under the row.foreach and it came up with the same issue

Comment: just a question why am i adding the parse twice if you look i am adding it under the try loop

Comment: yep ok i think i found the issue  const data = '{ "Company Name": "companyname", "service type": "service" }';

is not storing showing my responces from the database , any ideas